# SQL Server : Query Joining Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Trying to create a SQL Server query based on a challenge match system. There are two tables that I want to join in the query: `Users` and `ChallengeMatches`.

The columns in the `Users` table are `UserID, UserDisplayName`

The columns in the `ChallengeMatch` table are `ChallengeMatchID, ChallengerUserID, ChallengeeUserID`

Of course, all `ChallengeeUserID`'s and `ChallengerUserID`'s are listed in the `Users` table as unique users.  What I want the query to do is for each challenge match (row in the `ChallengeMatch` table), return the `UserDisplayName` of both of the challenge participants e.g. `PlayerName1`, `PlayerName2`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, did not know where to start in terms of matching the UserID with both the ChallengerUserID and the ChallengeeUserID to bring back the UserDisplayName for both.

Comment: Don't let what Borat discourage you you in asking questions.  If that works make sure you give @citsonga the credit..

Comment: [I added a SQL Fiddle to prove my answer works.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b00f8/3/0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to join the Users table twice. This should do the trick:

```
select 
    u1.UserDisplayName as [Challenger],
    u2.UserDisplayName as [Challengee]
from ChallengeMatch cm
left outer join Users u1
    on cm.ChallengerUserID = u1.UserID
left outer join Users u2
    on cm.ChallengeeUserID = u2.UserID
where cm.ChallengeMatchID = 2 /* specify value for relevant match */
```

[Here is a SQL Fiddle with this example working.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b00f8/3/0)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * FROM 
    (
      SELECT 'Challenger' [Type]
          ,ChallengerUserID [UserID] 
      from ChallengeMatch 
      where ChallengeMatchID=2
     UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Challengee' [Type]
           ,ChallengeeUserID [UserID] 
      from ChallengeMatch 
      where ChallengeMatchID=2
          ) as c
Inner join Users u
  ON c.UserID=u.UserID
```

Returns results in slightly different form than @Citsonga, but works too.
I would consider storing information more like how the nested select looks in general (Except Type would be an Int foreign Key to the user types table that you would need) for easier joins of this nature. It would also allow you to expand to more than 1 challenger/e per match